# How to check if all squares of a chessboard got stepped at least once?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following problem I can't figure out on my own.

There is a 2D array with 8x8 dimensions. A dog is randomly put within this dimension. The dog is not allowed to walk out of the dimension, if it does those steps are not counted. Every step the dog takes to another square is counted. Each simulation should calculate the number of overall steps it took for the dog to visit all squares of the 8x8 dimension at least once.

How do I know if all 64 squares got stepped at least once to stop the simulation and print the steps?

```
int [] [] dimension = new int [8][8];
boolean [] [] onSquare = new boolean [8] [8];

for (int i = 0; i < dimension.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dimension.length; j++) {
        dimension [i] [j] = j;
}
while (true) {
    int dog = rnd.nextInt(4)+1;

    if (dog == 1) {
      x++; // x,y show position of the dog
      counter++;
    }
    if (dog == 2) {
      x--;
    }
    if (dog == 3) {
      y++;
    }
    if (dog == 4) {
      y--;
}
```

Comment: What does "getting stepped" actually mean? Why is it important to do? It's kind of hard to understand what you're describing when you don't actually include the code you're talking about, so why don't you post some code that illustrates the problem? What you're doing is like asking a doctor for medical advice over the phone. Your code has to be examined to see what's really going on.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I need to know how I can check if every square got crossed at least once - I added the source code which should make it somewhat clear what I am meaning.

Comment: Do you want total step count when all the squares are covered? I don't get it. @dasblinkenlight already answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep track of the number of squares that have been visited at the same time as you flip your 2D array elements from "not visited" to "visited", like this:

```
int countVisited = 0;
...
// Flip from not visited to visited:
if (!visited[i][j]) {
    visited[i][j] = true;
    countVisited++;
}
```

Now your check for "all squares have been visited" simplifies to `if (countVisited == 64) ...`

Comment: So, all I have to do is to create a boolean array of the same size as the grid and for every step, within the grid flip it to true? When I am doing this I get <64 steps which should not be true as I expect >400 steps minimum to get on every square at least once - I edited the source code into the topic.